# Smoother projectile motion in Racket?

Tags: racket, game-physics

I'm playing a little with Racket big-bang mechanism, but I cannot get both smooth and fast going projectile. There's so much ugly flickering. Here's my code:

```
(require 2htdp/universe
         2htdp/image)

(define gx 0)
(define gy 0.35)

(struct ballstate (x y vx vy) #:transparent)

(define startstate (ballstate 10 590 7 -20))

(define (make-new-state old)
  (define newvx (+ (ballstate-vx old) gx))
  (define newvy (+ (ballstate-vy old) gy))
  (ballstate (+ (ballstate-x old) newvx)
             (+ (ballstate-y old) newvy)
             newvx
             newvy))


(define (main)
  (big-bang startstate
            [on-tick make-new-state]
            [to-draw place-ball-at]
            [on-key reset]))

(define (place-ball-at s)
  (place-image (circle 10 "solid" "red")
               (ballstate-x s)
               (ballstate-y s)
               (empty-scene 800 600)))

(define (reset s ke)
  startstate)

(main)
```

The question is: how to make it better, faster, smoother and flicker-free?

Comment: This seems relevant (but maybe not too helpful) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plt-scheme/HJDkNor277E

Comment: @DaoWen The 2htdp/universe has double buffering builtin.

Comment: @soegaard - If you read the whole thread you'll see the part at the bottom where they suggest the problem isn't double-buffering but the lack of support for redrawing only a small part of the canvas for updates. That's the part I was talking about, and the reason it's "not too helpful" is that there's no suggested work-around.

Comment: @daowen Okay - the thread was long, so thought it was the double buffering you were referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two things that might help:

1. The on-tick clause takes an optional parameter that determines the time between two ticks. The default is 1/28, so if you lower this you will get more frames resulting in a smoother animation.
2. If your program takes longer than the time between each tick to produce an image, you will see stuttering. Precomputing everything that can be precomputed is a good thing. For example, there is no reason to produce a new empty scene each time, so below I have simply stored it in a variable.

> ```
> (define (main)
>   (big-bang startstate
>             [on-tick make-new-state 1/50]
>             [to-draw place-ball-at]
>             [on-key reset]))
>
> (define background (empty-scene 800 600))
>
> (define (place-ball-at s)
>   (place-image (circle 10 "solid" "red")
>                (ballstate-x s)
>                (ballstate-y s)
>                background))
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but even with your changes the ball still flickers. :(

Comment: @RacketNoob Which platform are you using?

Comment: @RacketNoob Note that when twice as many frames are shown per second, you can reduce vx to half. Since the ball moves a smaller distance per frame, the result will be smoother.

Comment: @RacketNoob: Try with 1/100. It should be smoother. My guess is that you are not experiencing flickering (where you may see the erasure of (parts of) the previous frame and the drawing of the new frame), but [persistence of vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision) (which induces a stuttering, as soegaard puts it): as the ball jumps from one position to the other, but not fast enough, your eyes see it in two different places at once, and you may unconsciously interpret it as going back and forth between the old and the new position for a small period of time.